# Acts 1:19: "that field is called in their proper tongue" - spoken by Peter or by Luke?

Tags: acts, peter

> <sup>Acts 1:15</sup> And in those days Peter stood up in the midst of
>   the disciples, and said, (the number of names together were about an
>   hundred and twenty,)
>
> <sup>Acts 1:16</sup> Men [and] brethren, this scripture must needs
>   have been fulfilled, which the Holy Ghost by the mouth of David spake
>   before concerning Judas, which was guide to them that took Jesus.
>
> <sup>Acts 1:17</sup> For he was numbered with us, and had obtained
>   part of this ministry.
>
> <sup>Acts 1:18</sup> Now this man purchased a field with the reward of
>   iniquity; and falling headlong, he burst asunder in the midst, and all
>   his bowels gushed out.
>
> <sup>Acts 1:19</sup> **And it was known unto all the dwellers at
>   Jerusalem; insomuch as that field is called in their proper tongue,
>   Aceldama, that is to say, The field of blood.**
>
> <sup>Acts 1:20</sup> For it is written in the book of Psalms, Let his
>   habitation be desolate, and let no man dwell therein: and his
>   bishoprick let another take.
>
> <sup>Acts 1:21</sup> Wherefore of these men which have companied with
>   us all the time that the Lord Jesus went in and out among us,

As far as I know there are two views on the verse 19 in the passage above:

1. Verse 19 is the words spoken by Peter
2. Verse 19 is the insertion by Luke, and, therefore, they don't belong to Peter and should be taken in parentheses

I wonder what arguments do the supporters of the first view put forth.

I guess one of the arguments must be something like Peter refers to the dwellers of Jerusalem in the third person here because he himself was originally a dweller of Bethsaida of Galilee:

> <sup>John 1:43</sup> The day following Jesus would go forth into
>   **Galilee**, and findeth Philip, and saith unto him, Follow me
>
> <sup>John 1:44</sup> Now Philip was of Bethsaida, the **city of** Andrew
>   and **Peter**.

and, therefore, his native dialect was different from theirs:

> <sup>Mark 14:70</sup> And he denied it again. And a little after, they
>   that stood by said again to Peter, Surely thou art [one] of them: for
>   **thou art a Galilaean, and thy speech agreeth [thereto]**.

However, the fact that he was talking about the dwellers of Jerusalem in the third person should also mean then that those 120 men that were listening to Peter were not the dwellers of Jerusalem either. Was it the case?

Are there any other arguments supporting the first view?

Answer (score 2):

According to [Vincent word studies](http://vws.biblecommenter.com/acts/1.htm) the word  **'Akeldamach' is Aramaic**, the language then spoken in Palestine.

The reason why it seems legitamate to consider verses 18 and 19 to be within brackets as a comment of Luke, as in the ESV, is because the aduience to whom Peter is speaking to would have understood Aramaic as Peter was addressing a crowd in Jerusalem.

> (Now this man acquired a field with the reward of his wickedness, and falling headlong he burst open in the middle and all his bowels gushed out. 19 And it became known to all the inhabitants of Jerusalem, so that the field was called in their own language Akeldama, that is, Field of Blood.) (ESV  Acts 1:18-19)

Comment: "The other view is that Luke added to the words..." - but that's exactly the view # 2 in my question!

Comment: "I do not think you will scrape much up because of the Aramaic match" - Can you, please, explain what you mean here? I don't understand.

Comment: "this seems just to be a mistake not knowing the meaning of it in Aramaic" - You mean it's a mistake by Luke?

Comment: @brilliant - sorry about the confusion. I had not properly explained anything. Please re-read.

Comment: "Peter was addressing a crowd in Jerusalem" - Mike, I have some uneasiness with this argument. I mean the fact that those 120 were at that moment in Jerusalem doesn't automatically mean that they were the dwellers of Jerusalem. Acts 2:7 gives us quite a strong basis to think not only that all of the 120 were not the dwellers of Jerusalem, but even to suppose that it was evident (perhaps, from their physical appearance) that they were all from Galilee ("they were ... marvelled, saying one to another, Behold, are not all these which speak Galilaeans? ") and thus spoke the same dialect as Peter.

Comment: @brilliant - yes I can really go either way on this, maybe some in the crowd where not totally familiar with Aramaic in which case the parenthesis would not be needed. BTW need to change question to refer to Chapter 1.

Comment: "BTW need to change question to refer to Chapter 1"- Oh my! How did I notice it! Am going to change it right now.

Comment: "maybe some in the crowd where not totally familiar with Aramaic" - I don't quite understand how whether or not they were familiar with Aramaic is the point here. It seems to me that the main point is that, as Acts 2:7 shows, none of them was a dweller of (born and grew up in) Jerusalem. Thus, the dialect spoken in Jerusalem was not their native. So, it looks quite logical (to me) that Peter spoke to them about the dwellers of Jerusalem and their dialect in the 3rd person. It's quite possible that they all could speak Aramaic, however, not all of them were familiar with the 'Akeldamach' thing.

Comment: @brilliant - for some reason I did not realize you were specifically aksing for the alternate view, but I lean to the brackets theory. I do not mind if you just want me to delete this answer as it did not asnwer your question. Just let me know. I am not emotionally connected to either view.

Comment: No, no, no. Please, don't delete it. I am not emotionally connected to either view either. While I was asking this question I was indeed more lining toward the bracket theory, too. But now, having  discovered Acts 2:7, I am more in favor of no brackets. I just want to collect here all possible arguments in this matter - both those supporting the brackets, and those rejecting them - just to get as much objective view on this whole issue as possible.

Comment: @Mike, the audience of Peter's is already covered in v. 15. I find a more compelling argument for Lucan redaction in the audience of the writing itself. If Luke's Gospel has a Greek audience in mind, this may simply be a redaction by Luke to carry/explain the story to an audience unfamiliar with the scenario. Additionally, Luke is quite concerned with the Gentile mission, so this could be a way that Luke is letting the Gentile "in" on a Jewish meeting.

Comment: @swasheck - Aahh yes, good point that does make a stronger argument.

Comment: @Mike - I honestly don't see how swsasheck's point is a strong argument here. Perhaps, I don't see something here. Please, read my reply to his answer in my comments below.

Comment: @brilliant I guess it comes down to the fact of the relative benefit of the statement. What benefit does it do to speak to those in Jerusalem about those in Jerusalem about this circumstance that they already knew. Did Peter just have a momentary lapse of reason?

Comment: @swasheck - "What benefit does it do to speak to those in Jerusalem about those in Jerusalem" - I am sorry, but you can only be sure that in Acts 1:19 among those 120 some were of "those in Jerusalem" if you believe in the Luke's redaction theory. But if you look at it from the perspective of "no-Luke's-redaction" theory, then you wouldn't be sure that among those 120 some were "those in Jerusalem". In fact, you would be sure that all of the 120 were Galileans, who might've been able to speak the tongue of the Jerusalem dwellers (with accent), but might've not known about the 'field of blood'

Comment: @brilliant But the event happened after Jesus' crucifixion when the disciples were present. It is said that it was known to all who were in Jerusalem.

Comment: @swasheck - "It is said that it was known to all who were in Jerusalem" - Well, to be correct, it says "to all the dwellers (κατοικέω) of Jerusalem", not "to all who were in Jerusalem". Peter makes a clear distinction in Acts 2:14 between those who dwell in Jerusalem and those Jews who merely came to Jerusalem for celebrating the feast, among whom the 120 were, too. Plus, the phrase "in their own tongue" in Acts 1:19 indicates further that it is a reference to those who were born and grew up in Jerusalem - not those who came there with their other tongues.

Comment: That's true. So visitors are excluded from the knowledge of these events? Peter wouldn't have known about this, using this logic, which would necessitate the redaction perspective since he couldn't really have proclaimed something he didn't know. So then the disciples went from Jerusalem to their hometowns and got back within 2.5-3 days and assembled with the 12 just in time for the resurrection and for Jesus to "appear" in their midst? Additionally, the distinction that you refer to depends on whether or not Peter is actually speaking in 1:19, which is the source of debate.

Comment: "So visitors are excluded from the knowledge of these events?" - No, of course, they are not excluded from the knowledge of the events. However, they might've been excluded from the knowledge of the name of the 'field of blood' Aceldama. Note that the phrase "it became known to all the dwellers of Jerusalem" is not related to the 'field of blood'. Visitors might've well been aware of all the events taking place in Jerusalem (Luke 24:18), but not with all the names around there and their meanings (since it was not their native tongue and not their native place of living)

Comment: 'Plus, the phrase "in their own tongue" in Acts 1:19 indicates further that it is a reference to those who were born and grew up in Jerusalem - not those who came there with their other tongues.' Which also seems to confirm a redaction perspective since such a distinction wouldn't have needed to have been made if everyone was speaking the same language. To be sure, Galilean was not a different language, but a distinct dialect within a language. Much like "Southern English" vs. "Queen's English" vs. "American English" ...

Comment: "Additionally, the distinction that you refer to depends on whether or not Peter is actually speaking in 1:19, which is the source of debate" - I don't think it is a problem as the phrase "in their own tongue" in verses 19 shows clearly that the native dwellers of Jerusalem are meant.

Comment: @swasheck - "To be sure, Galilean was not a different language, but a distinct dialect within a language. Much like "Southern English" vs. "Queen's English" vs. "American English"" - But we still often have different names for different things even today between different dialects, isn't it? Another argument that makes the Luke-redaction theory less likely is that "τουτέστιν" ("that is to say"), which follows the word "Aceldama" is never used by Luke in his Gospel. It is used by him only one more time in Acts 19:4 and even there it is not used for interpreting the meaning of a Hebrew word.